# itDJ fails installation because FFmpeg is missing

Tags: mac, ffmpeg, itunes, mixer, dj

I am trying to install itDJ but the installation stops and the window says I must install FFmpeg.  It gives me the option to install it right then but it never downloads.  I installed ffmpeg from their site but when I rerun the itDJ is still errors saying ffmeg is not installed.  I have tried 3 different ways to install or maybe different versions of ffmpeg but itDJ still won't install erroring  out saying it's not installed, promting me to download it but download just hangs.  Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "you wen"?

Comment: It appears you meant to enter more information here John Harvey, but it was cut or or accidentally deleted. Please use the EDIT button to add the missing info to this question.

Comment: I fixed it the question I posted.  You should understand now.

Comment: @JohnHarvey, you need to be more specific. For example, how did you install itDJ? The authors, Macroplant don't even list it on their site and the only options appear from software aggregators like Softonic and MacUpdate and their listings are quite old.

Comment: I install ffmpeg from https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: I downloaded the static build dmg and install but when I tried to reinstall itDJ I got the error that mmfpeg was not installed, I then went back to ffmpeg.org and downloaded the static and shared dmg and install it but still itDJ install errored out saying mmfpeg was not installed, so then I ran "git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg" in a terminal window, again tried to install itDJ but once again received the error that ffmpeg was not installed.